# in mvc app, how to get authorization code?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

In .net framework , i used this :
      if (Request.Params["code"] != null)

What is the equalivalent for Core 2.2?

I tried this but no luck

```
         var request = HttpContext.Request;
        var query = request.Query;
```

Comment: Can you show the action you are defining?  Why do you need the authorization code, are you managing the authorization process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems you are manually requesting an authorization code in OAuth2/OIDC process .You can get the `code` from query string like :

```
var code= HttpContext.Request.Query["code"].ToString();
```

If you want to acquire access token with authorization code in the [OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code)  , you can refer to below code sample :

[Calling a web API in an ASP.NET Core web application using Azure AD](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore)

The key point is :

1. set `options.ResponseType = "id_token code";`
2. In `OnAuthorizationCodeReceived` event you can acquire access token which redeems the authorization code by calling `AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync` .See [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore/blob/master/TodoListWebApp/Extensions/AzureAdAuthenticationBuilderExtensions.cs#L63) .

Comment: Thanks guys .
In stackoverflow, how do i mark this as answered?

My problem is that i am missing response_type=code in my call to  "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2

Comment: i am following this example below - i need to modify it to ask for the code.


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp#option-2-register-and-manually-configure-your-application-and-code-sample

Comment: the code sample instead uses &response_type=id_token <--  is this a access token?  If so, then my code is complete . i was able to decrypt  theid_token   http://jwt.ms/  .

Comment: @user1224643 , mark answer by clicking the green check button

Comment: The code sample you provide is using openid connect middleware , you can get the token in OnAuthorizationCodeReceived  event , see my updated reply